# Cabal: How to configure transitive build-dependencies in the same project

Tags: haskell, cabal

I have a cabal project. It has library and test targets.

Test target depends on library because it tests the library's functionalities.

The problem is, whenever I add a package dependency to library (say, *cryptohash-sha1*)

```
library Lib
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  other-extensions:    DeriveGeneric
  build-depends:       base >=4.13 && <4.14,
                       cryptohash-sha1,
```

and run the test, I get error

> Could not load module ‘Crypto.Hash.SHA1’.
> It is a member of the hidden package ‘cryptohash-sha1-0.11.100.1’.
> Perhaps you need to add ‘cryptohash-sha1’ to the build-depends in your .cabal file

What I do in this situation is to add the same package to test target

```
test-suite json-generator-test
  hs-source-dirs:      test, src
  main-is:             Test.hs
  other-modules:       Lib
  build-depends:       base >=4.13 && <4.14
                       cryptohash-sha1,
```

Only then the test would run.

I want test target to automatically depend on all the packages from library target. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a cabal feature called *common stanzas*. You can read more about it in the following blog post:

- https://vrom911.github.io/blog/common-stanzas

With this approach, you can put all common dependencies in a separate stanza, and just import it in both the library and test suite:

```
common common-dependencies
  build-depends: base >=4.13 && <4.14
               , cryptohash-sha1

library Lib
  import:              common-dependencies
  exposed-modules:     Lib
  other-extensions:    DeriveGeneric

test-suite json-generator-test
  import:              common-dependencies
  hs-source-dirs:      test, src
  main-is:             Test.hs
  other-modules:       Lib
```

Comment: But it’s still not exactly a transitive build bependency resolution. It’s more of a syntax that helps you to copy & paste easier.
Does Cabal not support build dependency resolution between the targets within the same project?

Comment: @Ingun전인건 Cabal doesn't have a notion of transitive dependencies. Partially because Cabal strives to be a manifest file: specify everything explicitly and do as few implicit things as possible. In addition, you can name your local modules in the same way as modules in dependencies, and automatically adding all dependencies will introduce hard-to-debug conflicts.